# What is the right way for component composition in styled-components

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I struggle to decide what is the best practice approach and couldn't find the right answer for this common use case.

Stack: React, Styled-components, Typescript

I've built a component  that has 5 different presets for coloring(hover, active, etc.)

I have added a preset prop:

```
<Button preset="primary">
```

the question is should I just use this component with this prop or should I create a component for each preset:

```
const PrimaryButton = styled(Button).attr(() => {preset: "primary"})
```

and export each component?

Thanks!

Comment: Where you seen an advice for creating a component for each prop?

Comment: The question came from a discussion on my team, I did not find any advice like it but I also didn't find a good explanation as to when should I stop with "simplifying" components to the smallest use cases.
I'm pretty new to styled-components, if I would use just react component, the first option would've been my easy choice

Answer (score 0):

You should use the component with prop as it will help optimise your code. And code reusability will also be insured in this way as it is one of the primary benefit of react.

Comment: Can you please explain why is it more optimized? I can see why it makes less code to write but it also affects the compilation?

Comment: It ensures code reusability and when you are working on a big project or for a big company, each extra code of line matters. Also code reusability is what makes react so great and popular.